# Unable to create Mobile Account on AD Connected Mavericks Machine

Tags: macos, user-account, active-directory

Whenever I try to login as an AD user to an OS X Mavericks Macbook Pro it says unable to create mobile account. I do have the AD settings set to create a mobile account on login so that is correct but not really sure why it is failing. I have tried running the terminal command to create the mobile user (with verbose info on) and this is what it returns: (Username has been replaced with `<username here>`

```
bash-3.2$ sudo ./createmobileaccount -v -n <username here>
createmobileaccount built Nov 23 2013 15:20:29
verbose output on.
user name = "<username here>"
home path = "(null)"
user password = "(null)"
prompt for password = FALSE
encrypt new home = FALSE
create as external account = TRUE
home sync new account = FALSE
effective home path = /Users/<username here>
2013-12-20 08:14:17.753 createmobileaccount[9371:1303] ### authenticateUsingAuthorizationSync error:Error Domain=com.apple.systemadministration.authorization Code=-60007 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.systemadministration.authorization error -60007.)"
2013-12-20 08:14:23.145 createmobileaccount[9371:507] MCXCCacheMCXRecordAndGraph(): vproc_swap_integer(NULL, VPROC_GSK_PERUSER_SUSPEND, &(uid=10175887), NULL) failed
2013-12-20 08:14:23.146 createmobileaccount[9371:507] MCXCCacheMCXRecordAndGraph(): [localNode createRecordWithRecordType:dsRecTypeStandard:Users name:"<username here"] == 4001 (Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges.)
2013-12-20 08:14:23.808 createmobileaccount[9371:507] MCXCCacheMCXRecordAndGraph(): vproc_swap_integer(NULL, VPROC_GSK_PERUSER_RESUME, &(uid=10175887), NULL) failed
2013-12-20 08:14:23.809 createmobileaccount[9371:507] MCXCCreateMobileAccount(): Failed to create account. Error = 4001 (MCXCCacheMCXRecordAndGraph failed). Cleaning up mobile account record.
*** mobile account could not be created: 4001 (Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges.)
```

I have seen the lines stating that I do not have the appropriate privileges but I am running this as `sudo` with my admin user.

***Updated

I tried running the command using another admin account and got a different output

```
bash-3.2$ sudo ./createmobileaccount -v -n '<username here>'
createmobileaccount built Nov 23 2013 15:20:29
verbose output on.
user name = "'<username here>'"
home path = "(null)"
user password = "(null)"
prompt for password = FALSE
encrypt new home = FALSE
create as external account = TRUE
home sync new account = FALSE
effective home path = /Users/'<username here>'
2013-12-20 09:44:16.603 createmobileaccount[9616:1303] ### authenticateUsingAuthorizationSync error:Error Domain=com.apple.systemadministration.authorization Code=-60007 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.systemadministration.authorization error -60007.)"
2013-12-20 09:44:17.163 createmobileaccount[9616:507] MCXCCacheMCXRecordAndGraph(): vproc_swap_integer(NULL, VPROC_GSK_PERUSER_SUSPEND, &(uid=10175887), NULL) failed
2013-12-20 09:44:17.732 createmobileaccount[9616:507] MCXCCacheMCXRecordAndGraph(): vproc_swap_integer(NULL, VPROC_GSK_PERUSER_RESUME, &(uid=10175887), NULL) failed
2013-12-20 09:44:18.015 createmobileaccount[9616:507] MCXCCreateMobileAccount(): Failed to create account. Error = -6304 (mobile account file path is either not a directory or could not be properly created). Cleaning up mobile account record.
2013-12-20 09:44:18.019 createmobileaccount[9616:1303] ### authenticateUsingAuthorizationSync error:Error Domain=com.apple.systemadministration.authorization Code=-60007 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.systemadministration.authorization error -60007.)"
2013-12-20 09:44:18.102 createmobileaccount[9616:507] MCXCDeleteAccount(): vproc_swap_integer(NULL, VPROC_GSK_PERUSER_SUSPEND, &(uid=10175887), NULL) failed
2013-12-20 09:44:21.579 createmobileaccount[9616:1303] ### Error: setMachineArray:(
    {
    date = "2013-06-13 23:01:20 +0000";
    "dsAttrTypeStandard:RealName" = '<old deleted username1>';
    "dsAttrTypeStandard:UniqueID" = 503;
    name = '<old deleted username>';
},
    {
    date = "2013-06-13 23:01:51 +0000";
    "dsAttrTypeStandard:RealName" = "'<old deleted username2>'";
    "dsAttrTypeStandard:UniqueID" = 502;
    name = '<old deleted username>';
},
    {
    date = "2013-06-25 21:46:17 +0000";
    "dsAttrTypeStandard:RealName" = temp;
    "dsAttrTypeStandard:UniqueID" = 504;
    name = temp;
},
    {
    date = "2013-08-07 15:29:02 +0000";
    "dsAttrTypeStandard:RealName" = "'<old deleted username3>'";
    "dsAttrTypeStandard:UniqueID" = 501;
    name = '<old deleted username3>';
},
    {
    date = "2013-12-20 16:44:21 +0000";
    "dsAttrTypeStandard:RealName" = "username here";
    "dsAttrTypeStandard:UniqueID" = 10175887;
    name = "'<username here>'";
}
) forKey:deletedUsers inDomain:com.apple.preferences.accounts
2013-12-20 09:44:21.580 createmobileaccount[9616:507] MCXCDeleteAccount(): vproc_swap_integer(NULL, VPROC_GSK_PERUSER_RESUME, &(uid=10175887), NULL)failed
*** mobile account could not be created: -6304 (MCXCCreateMobileAccount(): [newUser createHomeDirectory] failed)
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it via user interface instead of terminal?

Answer (score 1):

We have ended up getting around the issue by running the command:

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/ManagedClient.app/Contents/Resources/createmobileaccount –v –P –n networkusername
```

We are still not sure why it wouldn't just automatically create the account but this has worked for what we needed.

Thanks