# systemsetup broken by Mavericks

Tags: macos

I have a couple of lines in my `.zshrc` file (although it could just as easily be my `.bashrc` file—the specific shell makes no difference) that use `systemsetup` to display the computer name and other similar things.  This worked flawlessly before I upgraded to Mavericks, but now it gives this error everytime (but still works anyway):

```
2013-12-24 15:21:20.575 systemsetup[3633:1403] ### authenticateUsingAuthorizationSync error:Error Domain=com.apple.systemadministration.authorization Code=-60007 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.systemadministration.authorization error -60007.)"
Computer Name: Tintin
```

(The first line is STDERR, and the second is STDOUT.)

Of course I could work around this by just piping STDERR to `/dev/null`, but I'd like to know what's wrong and fix the problem.

If I use `sudo` first, it works fine, the same as it always has worked.

The permissions on systemsetup are just what I would expect:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root   wheel       118K Oct 31 13:49 systemsetup
```

What is wrong?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Interesting… Running `systemsetup -getcomputername` works fine for me with no error, so it seems that it's related to your setup rather than a bug in Mavericks. [This question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114515/unable-to-create-mobile-account-on-ad-connected-mavericks-machine) shows exactly the same error in the output, but provided by `createmobileaccount` instead. Have you tried another user account? Apple's Developer documentation lists auth error -60007 as "The Security Server denied authorization because no user interaction is allowed."

Comment: The problem only ever appeared after upgrading to Mavericks, so I'd wager that Mavericks is somehow involved, even if it's not affecting everyone.

Comment: I saw that question, but couldn't glean anything useful from it.  I'm not using AD at all, and am not using any outside authentication server, so I'm utterly bewildered by the content of the error message.  What "Security Server" could be involved???